# Android: bottom popup activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-popupwindow

Hello : i want to make my activity appear like that my activity have a edittext with button inside cardview only
.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bottom Sheet Dialogs, follow step by step instructions on this site here:
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/bottom-sheet-dialogs-using-android-studio/

Comment: This site you mentioned was helpful but I want exact same bottom sheet that was visible in screen shot with border rounded and background transparent with slight dark tint.